# wxPython: "Super" wx.SpinCtrl with float values, layout inside sizer

Tags: python, wxpython, spinner, sizer

`wx.SpinCtrl` is limited to spinning across integers, and not floats. Therefore, I am building a `wx.TextCtrl` + `wx.SpinButton` combo class which enables me to spin across floats. I am able to size and layout both of them programmatically so that the combo looks exactly the same as an ordinary `wx.SpinCtrl`.

I am subclassing this combo from the `wx.TextCtrl` because I want its parent panel to catch `wx.EVT_TEXT` events. I would appreciate if you can improve on this argument of mine.

The `wx.EVT_SPIN_UP` and `wx.EVT_SPIN_DOWN` events from the `wx.SpinButton` are both internal implementations and the parent frame doesn't care about these events.

Now, I just hit a brick wall. My combo class doesn't work well with sizers. After `.Add()`ing the combo class to a `wx.GridBagSizer`, only the `wx.TextCtrl` is laid out within the `wx.GridBagSizer`. The `wx.SpinButton` is left on its own by itself. The `wx.EVT_SPIN*` bindings work very well, though.

My problem is the layout. How should I write the class if I want the `wx.GridBagSizer` to treat it as one widget?

Here is my combo class code:

```
class SpinnerSuper(wx.TextCtrl):
  def __init__(self, parent, max):
    wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=(48, -1))
    spin = wx.SpinButton(parent=parent, style=wx.SP_VERTICAL, size=(-1, 21))
    self.OnInit()
    self.layout(spin)
    self.internalBindings(spin)
    self.SizerFlag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER

    self.min = 0
    self.max = max

  def OnInit(self):
    self.SetValue(u"0.000")

  def layout(self, spin):
    pos = self.GetPosition()
    size = self.GetSize()
    RightEdge = pos[0] + size[0]
    TopEdge = pos[1] - (spin.GetSize()[1]/2 - size[1]/2)
    spin.SetPosition((RightEdge, TopEdge))

  def internalBindings(self, spin):
    spin.Bind(wx.EVT_SPIN_UP, self.handlerSpinUp(self), spin)
    spin.Bind(wx.EVT_SPIN_DOWN, self.handlerSpinDown(self), spin)

  def handlerSpinUp(CallerObject, *args):
    def handler(CallerObject, *data):
        text = data[0]
        prev = text.GetValue()
        next = float(prev) + 0.008
        text.SetValue("{0:0.3f}".format(next))
    return lambda event: handler(CallerObject, *args)

  def handlerSpinDown(CallerObject, *args):
    def handler(CallerObject, *data):
        text = data[0]
        prev = text.GetValue()
        next = float(prev) - 0.008
        text.SetValue("{0:0.3f}".format(next))
    return lambda event: handler(CallerObject, *args)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override DoGetBestSize() if you want your control to be
correctly managed by sizers. Have a look at [CreatingCustomControls](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls).

You could also have a look at [FloatSpin](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/FloatSpin.html) that ships with wxPython
(in wx.lib.agw) from version 2.8.9.2 upwards.

In response to your comments:

- Implementing DoGetBestSize() does not require drawing bitmaps directly. You just need to find a way, how you can determine the best size of your new widget. Typically you'd just use
  the sizes of the two widgets it is composed of (text + spinner) as basis.
- To let sizers treat two widgets as one, you can place them in another sizer.
- The recommended way to implement a custom widget with wxPython is to derive your new widget from wx.PyControl, add a sizer to it and add the two widgets you want to combine to that sizer.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look at `wx.lib.agw.FloatSpin`.  
About the other link you gave me (CreatingCustomControls), it requires drawing bitmaps directly, which I'm not willing to do at the moment.  
Is there a procedure in wxPython which enables a sizer to treat two widgets as one? It should be similar to the group function when drawing many objects in MS Word.

Comment: `FloatSpin` looks promising :) But this `wx.PyControl` with a `wx.Sizer` containing my `wx.TextCtrl` and `wx.SpinButton` is really interesting. I'm running into problems with `.SetSizer(sizer)`ing the `wx.PyControl`, but that would be another question. Thanks for the time, Ralph!

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in Kit's comments, `FloatSpin` is now the way to go.

It has been integrated in recent versions.

Here is a simple example of usage:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw.floatspin import FloatSpin

class Example_FloatSpin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example_FloatSpin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(480, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        spin = FloatSpin(panel, value=0.0, min_val=0.0, max_val=8.0, increment=0.5, digits=2, size=(100,-1))
        vbox.Add(spin, proportion=0, flag=wx.CENTER, border=15)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example_FloatSpin(None, title='Check FloatSpin')
    app.MainLoop()
```